# passing values between silverlight applications

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have created a Silverlight Business Application which runs as my main silverlight page. For each hyperlink button on my "menu" I launch another Silverlight Application which is created as a different project in Visual Studio. These are non-Business Applications.

Everything is working well. However I'm trying to pass a value from my main SL application to the SL application inside.
I have been googling a lot and cannot find an answer.
As I understand the InitParam is used between ASP and SL, and not between SL apps.
Since the App config is launched for the first SL app and the app config for the second application in never lauched, I'm not able to use that (thats at least my understanding)

The value I want to pass is the login name and role, which is possible to get from webcontext in the Silverlight Business application, but I'm unable to get webcontext in the non-Business application which run inside.

This is how I launch my SL app inside the main SL app:

```
    public Customers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Title = ApplicationStrings.CustomersPageTitle;

        if (WebContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Users") || WebContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
        {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(client_OpenReadCompleted);
        client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri("customers.xap", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }

    void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        string appManifest = new StreamReader(Application.GetResourceStream(new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, null),
            new Uri("AppManifest.xaml", UriKind.Relative)).Stream).ReadToEnd();

        XElement deploymentRoot = XDocument.Parse(appManifest).Root;
        List<XElement> deploymentParts =
            (from assemblyParts in deploymentRoot.Elements().Elements() select assemblyParts).ToList();

        Assembly asm = null;
        AssemblyPart asmPart = new AssemblyPart();
        foreach (XElement xElement in deploymentParts)
        {
            string source = xElement.Attribute("Source").Value;
            StreamResourceInfo streamInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, "application/binary"), new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative));

            if (source == "customers.dll")
            {
                asm = asmPart.Load(streamInfo.Stream);
            }
            else
            {
                asmPart.Load(streamInfo.Stream);
            }
        }

        UIElement myData = asm.CreateInstance("customers.MainPage") as UIElement;
        stackCustomers.Children.Add(myData);
        stackCustomers.UpdateLayout();
    }
```

Anyone?

Comment: I have to ask - why did you make them separate applications and not pages within the main application? You could use Prism to modularise the application if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

i agree with ChrisF ,I think that Prism or MEF can resolve you problem.
any way,do some search on the web and look for these two classes:
**

```
LocalMessageSender
LocalMessageReceiver
```

**

good luck